# POST request inserting null values into MS SQL db

Tags: node.js, angular, express, post

This is my code -

```
onSubmit(){ 
  var headers = new Headers();   
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let postParams = {
    firstName : this.firstName, 
    lastName : this.lastName,
    gender: this.myGender,
    myDate : this.myDate
  };

  this.http.post("ip/member", {postParams, headers}).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error); // Error getting the data
  });
}
```

I don't have a lot of experience with Angular so I'm not quite sure what's going on, but this is inserting null values into my MS SQL database. This is what the Node API looks like:

```
app.post('/member', function(req, res) {
    console.log("creating member\n");
    request = new Request("INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMemberInfo] VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @gender, @dateOfBirth);", function(err) {  
        if (err) {  
            console.log(err);}  
        });  
        request.addParameter('firstName', TYPES.VarChar , req.query.firstName);  
        request.addParameter('lastName', TYPES.VarChar, req.query.lastName);  
        request.addParameter('gender', TYPES.VarChar, req.query.gender); 
        request.addParameter('dateOfBirth', TYPES.Date, req.query.dateOfBirth); 

        request.on('doneProc', function(rowCount, more) {  
            console.log('Member added');  
        });       
       connection.execSql(request);      
 })
```

I've tried inserting using Postman and it works fine, and I've also ensured that all of my postParams in the Angular have values. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: on node.js which framework you are using.

Comment: I'm using Express

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line :

```
this.http.post("ip/member", {postParams, headers})
```

To :

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};

this.http.post("ip/member", postParams, httpOptions);
```

---

**As per Angular Offical Doc :**

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs)
```

Comment: [ts] Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'. I get this error if I do that.

Comment: Will you please also show the http injection , is it simple httpModule or httpClient ?

Comment: What do I need to import to get RequestOptions?

Comment: I'm currently using HttpClientModule and HttpClient

Comment: import { RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

Comment: I'm pretty sure angular/http is deprecated, angular/common/http replaces it and RequestOptions is not available within it.

Comment: @Egbert , then you should use HttpHeaders , check updated answer. That's why I have asked the about http ot httpClient :)

Comment: Looks like that did something, now I'm getting conversion failed while converting date and/or time from character string. I should probably be able to figure that out and if it fixes it, i'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, that did not work. Still shows up as null.

Comment: @Egbert , Now that you need to find from the express side :) , Console log(req.body) , check if you are getting data from angular or not

Comment: Hmm, looks like I'm not getting data in the express side. I did console.log for one of the values I'm supposed to get and it's showing up as undefined in the console when I run the post call. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with Angular. I see a an error from your nodeJS. You can't use `req.query`. It is a form post i believe so the form will be posting as body. I see that you are using express. So you should use `req.body` instead of `req.query`.

Note: If you are **not** using `body-parser` You must use `body-parser` the express middleware to be able to parse the body from a `POST` request.

Step1: `npm install --save body-parser`

Step2: Add this in your file containing express.

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Hope it helped!!

Comment: I added bodyParser = require('body-parser'); so it would recognize bodyParser. Still did not work unfortunately, values are NULL.

Comment: give me the screenshot of the values for req.body after bodyParser